# The set of left cosets, homogeneous space, and homotopy group

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, lie-groups, homotopy-theory, homogeneous-spaces

Here are statements that I attempt to make sure I am doing things on the right track.

Below we take $N=3$ for all $N$.

1. Consider the group:

> $$G=\frac{SU(N)_A \times SU(N)_B \times U(1)}{(\mathbb{Z}_N)^2},$$

this group can be understood as a triplet
$$(g_A, g_B, e^{i \theta}) \in SU(N)_A \times SU(N)_B \times U(1),$$
such that
$(e^{i \frac{2\pi}{N}}, 1, e^{-i \frac{2\pi}{N}})$ is the first $\mathbb{Z}_N$ generator mod out in $G$, while $(1,e^{i \frac{2\pi}{N}}, e^{-i \frac{2\pi}{N}})$ is the second $\mathbb{Z}_N$ generator mod out in $G$. Namely (1) the center of $SU(N)_A$, (2) the center of $SU(N)_B$ and (3) the $e^{i \frac{2\pi}{N}}\in U(1)$ overlap, thus we only mod out the twice redundant $(\mathbb{Z}_N)^2$.

Now consider the subgroup $H$ of the $G$ as:

> $$H=\frac{SU(N)_{A,B}}{\mathbb{Z}_N}\times \mathbb{Z}_2,$$

where
this group can be understood as a doublet
$(g_{A,B}, g_1) \in SU(N)_{A,B}\times \mathbb{Z}_2= (SU(N)_{A,B}, \{\pm 1 \}) =H \subset G,$
where there is a one-to-one correspondence between
$$(g_{A,B}, g_1) \in H$$ and $$(g_{A,B},g_{A,B}^*, g_1) \in G$$ with $g_{A,B}=g_A=g_B^*$, where $g_B^*$ means the complex conjugation (without the transpose $T$) of $g_B $.

Finally, we need $\frac{SU(N)_{A,B}}{\mathbb{Z}_N}$ to mod out ${\mathbb{Z}_N}$, where we consider 
$(g_{A,B}',g_{A,B}'^*)=(e^{i \frac{2\pi}{N}},e^{-i \frac{2\pi}{N}})\mathbb{I} \in {\mathbb{Z}_N}$;  this particular rank-$N$ diagonal matrix is the ${\mathbb{Z}_N}$ we modded out .

We have that
$$\frac{SU(N)_{A,B}}{\mathbb{Z}_N} \subset  SU(N)_A \times SU(N)_B, $$
$$ \mathbb{Z}_2 = \{\pm 1 \} \subset U(1). $$

So this explains how $H$ is embedded as a subgroup in $G$.

Question:

> - What is the **precise topological space** of the set of left coests
>     $$
>   G/H=\frac{\frac{SU(N)_A \times SU(N)_B \times U(1)}{(\mathbb{Z}_N)^2}}{\frac{SU(N)_{A,B}}{\mathbb{Z}_N}\times \mathbb{Z}_2}?
>   $$
>     Is this certain smooth homogeneous space like a sphere or a complex/real projective space?
> - What is the homotopy group?
>     $$
>   \pi_j(G/H)=?,
>   $$
>     for $j=1,2,3,4,5$.

---

Some background info that I made attempt and showed for your free use:

(1). $\pi_i(U(N))=\pi_i(\frac{SU(N)\times U(1)}{\mathbb{Z}_N})$: 
$$\pi_m(U(N))=\pi_m(SU(N)), \text{ for } m \geq 2$$
$$\pi_1(U(N))=\mathbb{Z}, \;\;\pi_1(SU(N))=0,$$

(2). $\pi_1(\mathbb{Z}_N)=\mathbb{Z}_N$ and $\pi_i(\mathbb{Z}_N)=0$ for $i\geq 2$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer, since on the one hand, I think there is a small error in your question and second the various quotients by centers got too complicated for me. (They only lead to some finite coverings and thus quotients in $\pi_1$ and isomorphisms in the higher $\pi_i$'a anyway.) What I think is an error in your question is that you can view 
$$\{(g,g^*):g\in SU(N)\}$$ as a subgroup in $SU(N)\times SU(N)$ since $$(gh)^*=h^*g^*$$ but not $g^*h^*$.

But for any Lie group you can take $G\times G$ and naturally view $G$ as the diagonal subgroup $\Delta:=\{(g,g):g\in G\}\subset G\times G$. As one may expect naively, the quotient $(G\times G)/\Delta$ is diffeomorphic to $G$ itself. (This is the standard way to view a Lie group as a symmetric space.) Explicitly, this diffeomorphism can be seen by considering the left action of $G\times G$ on $G$ defined by $(g,h)\cdot\tilde g:=g\tilde gh^{-1}$. Denoting by $e$ the neutral element of $G$, you see that $(g,e)\cdot e=g$, so the action is transitive and that $(g,h)\cdot e=e$ if and only if $gh^{-1}=e$ and hence $g=h$. Thus the isotropy group is $\Delta$ and hence $G\cong (G\times G)/\Delta$.

I am sure that a small adaption of this construction can be used to identify the homogeneous space you are interested in with something that is close to $U(N)$ or $SU(N)$, which should also allow identifying the homotopy groups.

Comment: thanks Andreas Cap, this helps +1

Comment: "What I think is an error in your question is that you can view $\{(g,g^*):g\in SU(N)\}$ as a subgroup in $SU(N)\times SU(N)$ since $(gh)^*=h^*g^*$ and not $g^*h^*$." can you clarify this?

Comment: The set of elements of the form $(g,g^*)$ is not closed under multiplication, since $(g,g^*)(h,h^*)=(gh,g^*h^*)$, but the only element in the subset with first component $gh$ is $(gh,(gh)^*)=(gh,h^*g^*)$.

Comment: for $g,h\in SU(N)$ the special unitary group, we have $g^*= (g^T)^{-1}$, while $g^\dagger= (g)^{-1}$. So $(gh)^*=((gh)^T)^{-1}=(h^T g^T)^{-1}=(g^T)^{-1}(h^T)^{-1}=g^* h^*$, here $T$ is the transpose, and $*$ is the complex conjugation (without the transpose).
The $(gh)^*=g^*h^*$ is true. Do you agree?

Comment: (I think you misunderstand my complex conjugation (without the transpose))

Comment: If $*$ just means complex conjugation, then it is OK (but this is very unusual notation).

Comment: thanks - it is my notation.